# How to validate a link showing 500 error in Selenium?

Tags: selenium

I am trying to validate the links of a website using server response code and page title, the server response found through the code shown below is 200 and page title is also same for all the pages.

the code is as follows:

```
if(url == null || url.isEmpty())
{
System.out.println("URL is either not configured for anchor tag or it is 
empty");
objExcelFile.writeExcel(filePath,"skipped_links",url);

        }

        else   if(!url.startsWith(homePage)){

            System.out.println("URL belongs to another domain, skipping it.");
            objExcelFile.writeExcel(filePath,"skipped_links",url);

        }
        else{
        try {
            huc = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url).openConnection());

            huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

            huc.connect();

            respCode = huc.getResponseCode();

            if(respCode != 200){
                System.out.println(url+" is a broken link");
                String Actualtitle = driver.getTitle();
                System.out.println(Actualtitle);
                System.out.println(respCode);



                objExcelFile.writeExcel(filePath,"broken_links",url);


            }
            else{
                 String Actualtitle = driver.getTitle();
                 System.out.println(Actualtitle);
               if (Actualtitle.contentEquals(unexpectedTitle)){
                   System.out.println(url+ " is a broken link");
                 objExcelFile.writeExcel(filePath,"broken_links",url);
               } else {
                   System.out.println(url+ " is a valid link");
                   System.out.println(respCode);

                 objExcelFile.writeExcel(filePath,"valid_links",url);
               }

            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The header is intact but the link is showing 500 error below the header. The issue is that even though page is showing 500 error, I am getting the server response code as 200, hence I am not able to make out whether this link is broken or not

This is the screenshot of the issue for the page I am validating :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH8V1.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. Hint: Post effort and code

Answer (score 0):

Once you induce **connect()** as in :

```
huc.connect();
```

You can write as many `for()` loops to check any condition of the **`Response Code`** invoking **`getResponseCode()`**  method as below :

```
if (huc.getResponseCode() == 200) 
{
    System.out.println(linkURL + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage());
}

if (huc.getResponseCode() == 500) 
{
    System.out.println(linkURL + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage());
}

if (huc.getResponseCode() == 404) 
{
    System.out.println(linkURL + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage());
}

if (huc.getResponseCode() == 402) 
{
    System.out.println(linkURL + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage());
}

if (huc.getResponseCode() == httpUrlConnect.HTTP_NOT_FOUND) 
{
    System.out.println(
            linkURL + " - " + huc.getResponseMessage() + " - " + huc.HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
}


} catch (IOException e) 
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: But the  issue is that I am getting response code as 200 which is for valid link, even though the page is showing 500 error, if I will use your code, it will consider the response code as 200 and will display it as valid link. I need to figure out a way to display that this link is broken. The server response code is not able to check for the valid link in this case. Could you please suggest a better way to do so?

Comment: @ShauryaNigam I have provided you the most comprehensive way to check ResponseCode. If any individual valid link is not responding as per the underlying protocols & standards Selenium/Java can't solve it. But I think my Answer does address your Question. Please Accept the Answer.

Comment: I really appreciate your response, but my issue has still not resolved. I need a solution to this problem.